# 1:n : Na/NaN argument while using ifelse

Tags: r

i Have a data frame "temp" as below

```
Value2
1000
1359
543
653
238
1652
```

i want to find no of intervals with certain parameters. I am using below code

```
tempCut <-290
tempMax<-1800
tempslab<-6
funX<-function(x,n){n=1:n*tempCut; findInterval(x,n)}
   temp$New <-ifelse(temp$Value2>=tempCut&temp$Value2<tempMax,funX(temp$Value2,tempslab),0)
```

but i am getting the error

```
Error in 1:n : Na/NaN argument.
```

i want to create a column using Findinterval

```
Value2|New
1000  |3
1359  |4
543   |1
653   |2
238   |0
1652  |5
```

Comment: Did you meant `slabs` instead of `tempslab`.  In that case `ifelse(temp$Value2>=tempCut&temp$Value2<tempMax,funX(temp$Value2,slabs),0)
#[1] 3 4 1 2 0 5`

Comment: yes . sorry, editing it now

Comment: using `slabs` get the expected output or the one you now changed to `tempslab`

Comment: @akrun i did that only but its throwing the error in 1:n

Comment: Could you please check the `str(temp)` as I can't reproduce the error with the example you showed.  Also, it is better to have braces around `(1:n)`